# Polynomial in two variables such that $P(x,y)=P(x+y,x-y)$

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

$P:R\times R \to R\times R$ is a polynomial with real coefficients. It is given that $P\left(x,y\right) = P\left(x+y,x-y\right)$. Find all such $P$.

Comment: Do you mean 2 polynomials or is it R x R \to R?

Comment: Use `\Bbb R` for $\Bbb R$

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish `\Bbb` is [deprecated](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22142)

Comment: @user10354138 This isn’t LaTeX so it’s fine. What’s your issue?

Comment: The polynomial is P only. R refers to the set of real numbers

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*: Apply $P(x,y)=P(x+y,x-y)$ once more and you get
$$
P(x,y)=P(x+y,x-y)=P(2x,2y).
$$

Comment: how to proceed after this?

Comment: What do you think we should do next, after obtaining $P(x,y)=P(2x,2y)$ for all $x,y$?

Comment: So P is a constant polynomial. Am I right??

Comment: Why must P be constant?

Comment: We get $P\left(2^{k}*x, 2^{k}*y\right)$ = $P\left(2^{j}*x, 2^{j}*y\right)$ for all $k,j$